# python3 relative imports when import modules from multiple locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-path

I am trying to import a module from multiple locations but can't get this to work because relative imports in Python3 have been disabled. I want to do this so users can copy package_1 and run this at the terminal (using main class); while another class is imported into scriptb.py which is a web-application front-end.

```
-- projectfolder
-- projectfolder/
-- __init__.py
--- package_1/
------ __init__.py
------ subpackage_a/
------ subpackage_a/core/module1.py
------ subpackage_a/__init__.py
------ subpackage_a/core/__init__.py
------ run.py
--- package_2/
----- __init__.py
-- -- scriptb.py
```

Here at the "package_1/run.py" imports: 
    from subpackage_a.core.module1 import classname

Here are the "package_2/scriptb" imports:
    package_1.run import classname

However when I run scriptb.py I get the following error in run.py
    ImportError: No module named 'package_1.core'

```
Traceback:
File "/directory/package_1/run.py", line 7, in <module>
    from subpackage_a.common.exceptions import Classname
ImportError: No module named 'subpackage_a.common'
```

Is there a better way to handle this then catching the ImportError exception and defining two import locations in all of the "package_a" modules?

or better than doing this which means importing each module twice

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    from package_1 import classname
else:
    from .package_1 import classname
```

Thanks

EDIT:

For future reference I had to do this in the subpackages to import other modules in the core folder

```
try:
    from package_1.core.module1 import classname:
except ImportError:
    from ..core.module2 import classname
```

as the following only works in main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from package_1.core.module1 import classname:
except ImportError:
    from .package_1.core.module2 import classname
```

Answer (score 1):

All the sub-directories must have **__init__.py** if you want to use it as a package. Try to implement the following file structure.

```
-- projectfolder
-- projectfolder/
-- __init__.py
--- package_1/
------ __init__.py
------ subpackage_a/
-----------__init__.py**********
------ subpackage_a/core/module1.py
-------------------core/
-----------------------__init__.py**********
------ run.py
--- package_2/
----- __init__.py
-- -- scriptb.py
```

add an  **__init__.py** file to the *subpackage_a* folder and *subpackage_a/core/* folder

**EDITED:** I think your way of handling this is a better option

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    from package_1 import classname
else:
    from .package_1 import classname
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All the packages have __init__.py file. I'll edit post as I forgot to type them in.

Comment: Damn, I can't use "if __name__ == '__main__': " inside subpackages as they aren't been called as the main program, so I'm still having the same problem doing that. Suppose I'll have to catch the ImportError exception..

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you can see by your folder structure and the uses of "subpackage_a" in "package_1/run.py" and "package_2/scriptb.py", actually, "subpackage_a" is not a subpackage of "package_1". Better adapt your project to the realities and make "subpackage_a" a real package and make it installable into python using distutils or something similar. Then both "run.py" and "scriptb.py" can use it without reverting to any relative import hacks.